# How do I show the binlog_format on a MySQL server?

Tags: mysql, query

How do I show the `binlog_format` on a MySQL server?

And if I dont like it how do I set it to *XX* permanently?

Where *XX* is `STATEMENT`, `ROW` or `MIXED`.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Matt Healy answered the question on how to show/set the format from the mysql client (on a running server) with `SET GLOBAL binlog_format = [STATEMENT|ROW|MIXED]`

To set the value permanently, and assuming you have access to the my.cnf, add:

```
[mysqld]
...

binlog_format=XX

...
```

and then restart your server.

Comment: straightforward and concise. +1 !!!

Comment: > [mysqld] .....
> > binlog-format=XX
> > ..... That needs to be binlog_format=XXX Underscore!

Comment: @Jeff When mysqld reads /etc/my.cnf, it totally understands both dashes (-) and underscores (_). In the mysql client, an underscore is mandatory. +1 anyway, and welcome to the DBA StackExchange !!!

Comment: @jeff thanks! It's strange that they flip flop between '-' and '_', but the [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_binlog-format) definitely say the option file parameter is `binlog-format=format`

Comment: I think binlog-format (with dash) is used from the command line, while binlog_format (with underscore) is the system variable name.

Answer (score 32):

To see the current binlog_format value:

```
mysql> show variables like 'binlog_format';
+---------------+-----------+
| Variable_name | Value     |
+---------------+-----------+
| binlog_format | STATEMENT |
+---------------+-----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

To change it:

```
mysql> SET GLOBAL binlog_format = 'STATEMENT';
mysql> SET GLOBAL binlog_format = 'ROW';
mysql> SET GLOBAL binlog_format = 'MIXED';
```

Source: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/binary-log-setting.html